# Metadata SOAP API can't parse response, Apex type not found for element

Tags: metadata-api, soap, wsdl

I've generated an Apex class based on the Metadata WSDL file I got from my org. I call the readMetadata function and while the response received contains all the data I want, the callout fails because of 'Apex type not found for element language'. What is missing from the generated code that it can't parse responses?

The response looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <readMetadataResponse>
            <result>
                <records xsi:type="CustomLabel">
                    <fullName>Accepted</fullName>
                    <language>en_US</language>
                    <protected>true</protected>
                    <shortDescription>Accepted</shortDescription>
                    <value>Accepted</value>
                </records>
                <records xsi:type="CustomLabel">
                    <fullName>Rejected</fullName>
                    <language>en_US</language>
                    <protected>true</protected>
                    <shortDescription>Rejected</shortDescription>
                    <value>Rejected</value>
                </records>
            </result>
        </readMetadataResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Andrew Fawcett](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/286/andrew-fawcett) has done a lot of work on using this API from Apex. Some of the issues are listed in his [Challanges calling the Metadata API from Apex](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi#user-content-challanges-calling-the-metadata-api-from-apex), such as polymorphic types that the Apex WSDL tooling can't handle.

So rather than the WSDL emitted by an org, that [financialforcedev/apex-mdapi Git project](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) is the best place to start.